# Android SocketTimeoutException to concurrent users on WiFi using Retrofit / OkHttpClient

Tags: android, sockets, retrofit2, okhttp, socket-timeout-exception

I saw a similar question but couldn't get an answer.

I read the data from mysql to php in linux server and then I put it on the list.
In a cellular network, it is okay to have multiple concurrent connections, but it is not possible to have multiple connections at the same time within the same Wi-Fi network.

Of course, there are no problems with the web browser, but only problems occur when connecting to the smartphone terminal.
I used several terminals like SAMSUNG Galaxy 6 and 4.

I don't think it's a coded bug.

If the first connected terminal calls the call.enqueue from the WIFI network, it is likely that socket is not release after use.

If someone has done it and solved it, give me an idea!

Note that the source is as follows :

```
public class ApiService {
    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        OkHttpClient httpClient=new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(0, 1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS))
                .build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(""http://www.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}



@GET("center_list_select_by_center_gubun.php")
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"})
Call<CenterModel> getCenterListByCenterGubun(@Query("center_gubun") String center_gubun,
                                            @Query("article_id") String article_id,
                                            @Query("on_list") String on_list);


api = ApiService.createService(ApiInterface.class);
Call<CenterModel> call = api.getCenterListByCenterGubun(tab_gubun_s, String.valueOf(lastId), "1");
call.enqueue(new Callback<CenterModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<CenterModel> call, @NonNull Response<CenterModel> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            if (response.body() == null || response.body().getResult() == null)  {
                return;
            }

            ArrayList<CenterModel.data> resultData = response.body().getResult();
            CenterModel.data lastData = resultData.get(resultData.size()-1);   

            if (lastData.id != null) {
                if (lastId > Integer.valueOf(lastData.id)) {     
                    lastId = Integer.valueOf(lastData.id);
                    isLoaded = false;
                    setResponseData(resultData, isNew);
                    dataList.addAll(resultData);
                }
            } else {                                               
                isLoaded = true;
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error:"+String.valueOf(response.code()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<CenterModel> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {      Log.e(TAG,  t.toString());
        if (t.toString().split(":")[0].equals("java.net.SocketTimeoutException")) MyUtils.wifiAlert(getContext());
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no problem if i connect to other servers in the same way. Is there a problem with setting up the server?
I checked with someone saying it was tcp_timestamps issue and it was already set up.

Comment: It was not a source but a server setup issue. After changing the server, it works without any problems.